# Sharepoint permissions working only on Default Groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-permissions

I have a SharePoint site with default groups and permissions. But only the users in the group *Site Owners* and *Site Members* are able to access the site.

When I tried creating **new** groups and assign permissions to the group, still the users in the new groups are not able to access the site.

Also, I tried giving permissions to user directly on site.

They get Access denied error. What might be the reason for this? Is this a permission issue or something else?

**Edit**:
When I gave full control access to user on site. He is able to access the site settings and site contents of site. Pages library settings is accessible but pages give the "Access Denied Error".

Comment: Maybe homepage that they are trying to open has unique permissions?

Comment: This is most likely caused by an unpublished homepage. If that is not the case, check the permissions on the Homepage and the masterpages. Make sure there is no broken permissions. Another issue could be a not published masterpage if you have a custom one.

Comment: No page has unique permissions.

Comment: have you created custom master page or page layout?

Comment: yes, I have created custom page layout.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue before. In my case the custom page layout I was using was not published on site.

Please check following points:

1. User has the permission on the custom master page/page Layout you are using.
2. You have published the latest version of the custom master page/page layout.
3. User has the permission on "Pages" library.
4. The custom master page/page layout is hidden or not?

Comment: Oh yes! I checked the Page Layouts and Published the Page layout which I was using and that solved my issue. Thanks Alot!